# how resize number of minions in gcloud? (kubernetes, gcloud)

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes

I created a cluster in google compute using the command:

```
./kube-up.sh
```

Kubernetes has created 1 master and 4 minios servers. I try delete two minions in google cloud and are reloaded.

I try also deleting the kubernetes minions with kubectl and after delete de VM. This fails.

```
kubectl delete nodes kubernetes-minion-XXX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kube-up.sh` created a managed instance group with size 4 which caused 4 nodes to be created. If you delete a node, the managed instance group will replace it so that you always have 4 nodes. You can change the number of nodes in the managed instance group by navigating to the "Instance Groups" link in the sidebar (under Compute -> Compute Engine), clicking on the group name, clicking Edit Group, and then changing the integer in the Number of Instances field.

If you want to delete your cluster, including all node VMs, you should run `kube-down.sh`.